# Javascript Curly braces weird behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code,

```
    if (options.max) {
        if (i <= options.max) $(x).addClass("hey");
    }
    else {
        if (i >= options.min) $(x).addClass("no"); //<- this
    }
```

Erasing every curly brace *from above* makes the second clause (marked with `<- this`) not work.

```
    if (options.max)
        if (i <= options.max) $(x).addClass("hey");
    else
        if (i >= options.min) $(x).addClass("no"); //<- this
```

I thought single expressions for if statements in JavaScript can be used without curly braces. Why is this happening?

Comment: If you remove the brace then you should also remove if from //<- this and the code actually what you want would be go wrong way thus use curly brace

Comment: All is working fine.. Try to show more code [http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/6/](http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/6/)

Comment: even after removing the braces its working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/yPYDJ/8/

Comment: Could you guys check my update?

Comment: This is not python so without braces, the `else` becomes `else` of `if (i <= options.max)`

Answer (score 5):

If the curly braces are removed, the `else` applies to the second `if`, i.e.:

```
if (options.max)
    if (i <= options.max) $(x).addClass("hey");
    else
        if (i >= options.min) $(x).addClass("no"); //<- this
```

The curly braces are required to ensure that the `else` is applied to the entire statement, however the second set may be removed, i.e.:

```
if (options.max) {
    if (i <= options.max) $(x).addClass("hey");
}
else
    if (i >= options.min) $(x).addClass("no"); //<- this
```

---

Another way is to replace the inner if-statements with the `&&` operator, such as the following.

```
if (options.max)
    i <= options.max && $(x).addClass("hey");
else
    i >= options.min && $(x).addClass("no");
```

*Note: This works because the expression will 'short-circuit' if the operand before `&&` equates to false.*